# Python Subprocess - SQLCMD (Executing sql scripts)

Tags: python, subprocess, sqlcmd

I am working on SQL Deployment through SQLCMD which will be calling from Python wrap up program. suppose if say that i am executing 3 sql scripts(.sql) and one script got failed i want to rollback the other 2 also at end.Could any one suggest me on this?2

i am expecting transactional handling while execting sql scripts

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use ODBC directly from python? You can't really have a database transaction if you're running separate sqlcmd processes, because those are different connections.